# VS2010 - what is the current library of choice for performing various sql admin tasks from C#

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, smo, sqldmo

I've been tasked with writing a C# Winforms application to simplify some of our common SQL admin tasks.

In the past I've worked with various SQL libraries which have simplified many aspects of the task such as interrogating and amending the schema, creating tables, stored procedures etc but it's been a while.

Is SQL SMO still the preferred library of choice (VS2010, SQL Server 2005 and later)?

Some of the tasks I need to perform are:

- Provide a list Servers
- Provide a list of Databases when a Server is selected
- List tables
- Iterate through objects (tables, columns, procedures, views, triggers)
- Interrogate object meta data - primarily on tables and columns
- Create tables, stored procedures and perhaps views and triggers.

(I'm developing in VS 2010)

thanks

Matt

Answer (score 1):

SMO is what I would say.

Is there something is doesn't do that you need, or are you just doing a sanity check to make sure you're using the latest?